# Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value during migration EF 6

Tags: datetime, entity-framework-6, database-migration, datetime2

When applying a migration using "update-database" I get an error about conversion of datetime2 to datetime. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh...  I found the answer. You have to add the following line to the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```